# Python Azure Function Service Bus Queue trigger doesn't work

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, serverless

I have created a Service Bus Queue in Azure and a deployed Azure Function that is triggered when new data is added to the queue. I also have a DB on azure, where I store the messages and a separate route in an Azure Function `get-all-data` that gets all the data from the DB.

However, the function doesn't get triggered when I add new data to the queue. Also, accessing `get-all-data` at `{auzrefunction-uri}/api/get-all-data` gives `404` response.

*Update*: I didn't really change anything, but `get-all-data` HTTP trigger started working. The problem with Service Bus trigger, however, is still the same.

I'm running and deploying the code using `VS Code` with Azure extension. I did everything by Microsoft's documentation.

After running localy, it seems that no functions are found inside my project:

The primary error message:

**No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).**

More detailed description:

```json
func start --verbose
Found Python version 3.9.5 (py).

                  %%%%%%
                 %%%%%%
            @   %%%%%%    @
          @@   %%%%%%      @@
       @@@    %%%%%%%%%%%    @@@
     @@      %%%%%%%%%%        @@
       @@         %%%%       @@
         @@      %%%       @@
           @@    %%      @@
                %%
                %


Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.4704 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.7.3.18953

[2023-12-11T00:22:53.287Z] Building host: startup suppressed: 'False', configuration suppressed: 'False', startup operation id: '319236c6-d816-43f6-a8e4-69d90415285c'
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.295Z] Reading host configuration file 'D:\Books\Labs\Cloud\lab3-func\host.json'
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.299Z] Host configuration file read:
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.300Z] {
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.301Z]   "version": "2.0",
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.302Z]   "logging": {
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.303Z]     "applicationInsights": {
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.304Z]       "samplingSettings": {
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.305Z]         "isEnabled": true,
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.306Z]         "excludedTypes": "Request"
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.307Z]       }
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.309Z]     }
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.310Z]   },
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.311Z]   "extensionBundle": {
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.312Z]     "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.313Z]     "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.314Z]   }
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.315Z] }
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.341Z] FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to python. Skipping WorkerConfig for language:java
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.344Z] FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to python. Skipping WorkerConfig for language:node
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.347Z] FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to python. Skipping WorkerConfig for language:powershell
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.354Z] Looking for extension bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle at C:\Users\user\.azure-functions-core-tools\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.358Z] Found a matching extension bundle at C:\Users\user\.azure-functions-core-tools\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle\3.24.0
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.372Z] Loading functions metadata
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.375Z] Reading functions metadata
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.377Z] Reading functions metadata
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.382Z] 0 functions found
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.385Z] 0 functions found
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.389Z] 0 functions loaded
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.391Z] Looking for extension bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle at C:\Users\user\.azure-functions-core-tools\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.393Z] Found a matching extension bundle at C:\Users\user\.azure-functions-core-tools\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle\3.24.0
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.395Z] Fetching information on versions of extension bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle available on https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/ExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/index.json
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.559Z] Skipping bundle download since it already exists at path C:\Users\user\.azure-functions-core-tools\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle\3.24.0
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.564Z] Loading extension bundle from C:\Users\user\.azure-functions-core-tools\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle\3.24.0\bin
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.567Z] Script Startup resetting load context with base path: 'C:\Users\user\.azure-functions-core-tools\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle\3.24.0\bin'.
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.576Z] Reading host configuration file 'D:\Books\Labs\Cloud\lab3-func\host.json'
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.578Z] Host configuration file read:
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.579Z] {
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.580Z]   "version": "2.0",
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.581Z]   "logging": {
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.583Z]     "applicationInsights": {
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.584Z]       "samplingSettings": {
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.585Z]         "isEnabled": true,
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.586Z]         "excludedTypes": "Request"
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.587Z]       }
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.587Z]     }
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.588Z]   },
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.589Z]   "extensionBundle": {
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.590Z]     "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.591Z]     "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.593Z]   }
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.594Z] }
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.853Z] FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to python. Skipping WorkerConfig for language:java
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.855Z] FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to python. Skipping WorkerConfig for language:node
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.857Z] FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to python. Skipping WorkerConfig for language:powershell
[2023-12-11T00:22:53.954Z] Initializing Warmup Extension.
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.007Z] Initializing Host. OperationId: '319236c6-d816-43f6-a8e4-69d90415285c'.
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.018Z] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, OperationId=319236c6-d816-43f6-a8e4-69d90415285c      
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.042Z] LoggerFilterOptions
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.043Z] {
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.046Z]   "MinLevel": "None",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.047Z]   "Rules": [
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.048Z]     {
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.049Z]       "ProviderName": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.050Z]       "CategoryName": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.051Z]       "LogLevel": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.052Z]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.053Z]     },
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.054Z]     {
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.055Z]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.056Z]       "CategoryName": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.057Z]       "LogLevel": "None",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.058Z]       "Filter": null
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.059Z]     },
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.061Z]     {
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.062Z]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.063Z]       "CategoryName": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.064Z]       "LogLevel": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.065Z]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.066Z]     },
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.067Z]     {
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.068Z]       "ProviderName": "Azure.Functions.Cli.Diagnostics.ColoredConsoleLoggerProvider",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.069Z]       "CategoryName": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.071Z]       "LogLevel": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.071Z]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.072Z]     }
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.073Z]   ]
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.074Z] }
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.076Z] LoggerFilterOptions
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.077Z] {
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.078Z]   "MinLevel": "None",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.080Z]   "Rules": [
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.081Z]     {
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.082Z]       "ProviderName": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.083Z]       "CategoryName": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.084Z]       "LogLevel": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.085Z]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.086Z]     },
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.087Z]     {
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.088Z]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.089Z]       "CategoryName": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.090Z]       "LogLevel": "None",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.091Z]       "Filter": null
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.092Z]     },
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.093Z]     {
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.095Z]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.096Z]       "CategoryName": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.097Z]       "LogLevel": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.098Z]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.099Z]     },
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.100Z]     {
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.101Z]       "ProviderName": "Azure.Functions.Cli.Diagnostics.ColoredConsoleLoggerProvider",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.102Z]       "CategoryName": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.103Z]       "LogLevel": null,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.104Z]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.105Z]     }
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.106Z]   ]
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.107Z] }
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.108Z] ConcurrencyOptions
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.109Z] {
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.110Z]   "DynamicConcurrencyEnabled": false,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.112Z]   "MaximumFunctionConcurrency": 500,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.113Z]   "CPUThreshold": 0.8,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.114Z]   "SnapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.115Z] }
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.116Z] FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.117Z] {
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.118Z]   "BatchSize": 1000,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.119Z]   "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.120Z]   "IsEnabled": true
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.121Z] }
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.122Z] SingletonOptions
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.123Z] {
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.124Z]   "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.125Z]   "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.126Z]   "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.127Z]   "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.128Z]   "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.129Z] }
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.132Z] Starting JobHost
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.136Z] Starting Host (HostId=desktopjcuvdfa-1433332689, InstanceId=c16617d5-921b-4758-a9c6-dca27fe2e074, Version=4.7.3.18953, ProcessId=9472, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=(null))
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.141Z] FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to python. Skipping WorkerConfig for language:java
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.143Z] FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to python. Skipping WorkerConfig for language:node
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.145Z] FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to python. Skipping WorkerConfig for language:powershell
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.158Z] Loading functions metadata
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.160Z] Reading functions metadata
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.161Z] Reading functions metadata
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.163Z] 0 functions found
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.164Z] 0 functions found
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.172Z] 0 functions loaded
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.192Z] Generating 0 job function(s)
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.212Z] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.221Z] HttpOptions
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.222Z] Initializing function HTTP routes
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.223Z] {
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.224Z] No HTTP routes mapped
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.226Z] 
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.225Z]   "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.228Z]   "EnableChunkedRequestBinding": false,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.229Z]   "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.230Z]   "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.231Z]   "RoutePrefix": "api"
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.233Z] }
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.235Z] Host initialized (87ms)
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.238Z] Host started (98ms)
[2023-12-11T00:22:54.239Z] Job host started
[2023-12-11T00:22:59.063Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000003014F25D'.
```

Here's my function at `function_app.py`:

```python
import azure.functions as func
import mysql.connector
import logging
import json
from datetime import datetime

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="my-function")
@app.service_bus_queue_trigger(arg_name="azservicebus", queue_name="my-sb-queue",
                               connection="sb://name.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=someRandomKeyLetters=") 
def servicebus_queue_trigger(azservicebus: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus Queue trigger processed a message: %s',
                azservicebus.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
    try:
        message_body = azservicebus.get_body().decode('utf-8')
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user="user", password="pwd", host="db-name.mysql.database.azure.com", port=3306, database="sensors")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Extract data from the message
        sensor_type = message_body['sensor_type']
        location = message_body['location']
        date = message_body['date']
        property_value = message_body['property']

        # Convert date string to datetime object
        date_obj = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')

        # Insert data into the database
        insert_query = (
            "INSERT INTO sensor_data (sensor_type, location, date, property) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
        )
        insert_values = (sensor_type, location, date_obj, property_value)

        cursor.execute(insert_query, insert_values)
        conn.commit()

        # Close the database connection
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

@app.route(route="get-all-data", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS) 
def get_all_data(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user="user", password="pwd", host="db-name.mysql.database.azure.com", port=3306, database="sensors")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Select all data from the database
        query = "SELECT * FROM sensor_data"
        cursor.execute(query)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        # Close the database connection
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

        # Convert database rows to a list of dictionaries
        data = []
        for row in rows:
            entry = {
                'id': row[0],
                'sensor_type': row[1],
                'location': row[2],
                'date': row[3].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), 
                'property': row[4]
            }
            data.append(entry)

        # Return the data as an HTTP response
        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype="application/json", status_code=200)

    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
```

My `host.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

My `local.settings.json`:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade the `Azure function core tools` to latest version. You can download it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows).

I have `Azure function core tools` version `4.0.5455` and used `"version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"` in `host.json`.

```
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
```

I have used your code and made changes in `# Extract data from the message`, which worked for me.

**`function_app.py`:**

```py
from datetime import datetime
import json
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import mysql.connector

app = func.FunctionApp()
@app.function_name(name="function")
@app.service_bus_queue_trigger(arg_name="azservicebus", queue_name="sbqueue",
                               connection="ServiceBusConnectionString") 
def servicebus_queue_trigger(azservicebus: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus Queue trigger processed a message: %s',
                azservicebus.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
    try:
        message_body = azservicebus.get_body().decode('utf-8')
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user="user", password="password", host="mysbsqlserver.mysql.database.azure.com", database="mysqldatabase", port=3306)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Extract data from the message
        sensor_type = json.loads(message_body)['sensor_type']
        location = json.loads(message_body)['location']
        date = json.loads(message_body)['date']
        property_value = json.loads(message_body)['property']

        # Convert date string to datetime object
        date_obj = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')

        # Insert data into the database
        insert_query = (
            "INSERT INTO sensor_data (sensor_type, location, date, property) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
        )
        insert_values = (sensor_type, location, date_obj, property_value)

        cursor.execute(insert_query, insert_values)
        conn.commit()

        # Close the database connection
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")



@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user="user", password="password", host="mysbsqlserver.mysql.database.azure.com", database="mysqldatabase", port=3306)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Select all data from the database
        query = "SELECT * FROM sensor_data"
        cursor.execute(query)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        # Close the database connection
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

        # Convert database rows to a list of dictionaries
        data = []
        for row in rows:
            entry = {
                'sensor_type': row[0],
                'location': row[1],
                'date': row[2].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                'property': row[3]
            }
            data.append(entry)

        # Return the data as an HTTP response
        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype="application/json", status_code=200)

    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
```

**`local.settings.json`:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "ServiceBusConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://sbtriggerbus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=xxxx;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxx"
  }
}
```

**`host.json`:**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

`sample message`:

```
{
    "sensor_type": "Temperature",
    "location": "Room1",
    "date": "2023-12-11",
    "property": "22.5"
}
```

[image]

[image]

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5455 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.27.5.21554

[2023-12-11T07:37:50.503Z] Customer packages not in sys path. This should never happen! 
[2023-12-11T07:37:56.429Z] 0.04s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
[2023-12-11T07:37:56.434Z] 0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
[2023-12-11T07:37:56.438Z] 0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
[2023-12-11T07:37:56.442Z] 0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[2023-12-11T07:37:56.802Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        http_trigger:  http://localhost:7071/api/http_trigger

        function: serviceBusTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-12-11T07:38:02.928Z] Executing 'Functions.function' (Reason='(null)', Id=e4bf05af-0063-41d4-938c-34dd9d137445)
[2023-12-11T07:38:02.935Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: e91b40c62e464d24bd45bcf049ed913c, SequenceNumber: 19, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2023-12-11T07:38:02.5330000+00:00, LockedUntilUtc: 2023-12-11T07:39:02.5640000+00:00, SessionId: (null)       
[2023-12-11T07:38:03.214Z] Python ServiceBus Queue trigger processed a message: {
[2023-12-11T07:38:03.220Z]     "sensor_type": "Temperature",
[2023-12-11T07:38:03.224Z]     "location": "Room1",
[2023-12-11T07:38:03.228Z]     "date": "2023-12-11",
[2023-12-11T07:38:03.232Z]     "property": "22.5"
[2023-12-11T07:38:03.236Z] }
[2023-12-11T07:38:06.972Z] Executed 'Functions.function' (Succeeded, Id=e4bf05af-0063-41d4-938c-34dd9d137445, Duration=4055ms)
[2023-12-11T07:38:16.644Z] Executing 'Functions.http_trigger' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=72fa1b5e-8c64-4433-a2c5-e9c3301a38f4)
[2023-12-11T07:38:16.667Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2023-12-11T07:38:19.815Z] Executed 'Functions.http_trigger' (Succeeded, Id=72fa1b5e-8c64-4433-a2c5-e9c3301a38f4, Duration=3179ms)
```

`http_trigger output`:

```
[
    {
        "sensor_type": "Temperature",
        "location": "Room1",
        "date": "2023-12-11",
        "property": "22.5"
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: How can upgrading azure functions core tools help me solve deployment problems on Azure? Isn't it just for runnung locally?

Comment: Btw, I have the latest version of az-core-tools

Comment: @Sgg8 when you upgrade the Azure Function core tools, it upgrades Azure function runtime version to latest version when your runtime version is lower version function doesn't work. As you are using python v2 model it is mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#development-options) that it only supports 4.x version. it is much better to use latest version of core tool and `"version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"` in `host.json`.

Comment: I did try to change the version like that and still had no success

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I spent around `15` hours trying different things, yet it started working for absolutely no reason after trying to deploy and redeploy this very code a few times in a row.